# Colorfunction of Arrow

Tags: color

I want to plot an arrow with a gradient of color. For example, the arrow is

```
Graphics3D[{Red,Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,0,2}}]}]
```

Then I want the Opacity is a function of 'z' coordinate, so that Opacity is 0 at the beginning and 1 at the end of the arrow.

How to modify the code above?

Comment: See my answer for a simple gradient of two colors. I'd too would be interested to know how to apply `ColorFunction` to a `Line`/`Arrow`

Answer (score 3):

For a simple gradient you could use `Line` together with `Arrow` since `Line` accepts a `VertexColors`-option.

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Arrow@Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, 
VertexColors -> {Directive[Red, Opacity@0], Red}]}]
```

[image: image of arrow]

Comment: What if I want the opacity is 0 at the start and the end, and opacity is 1 in the middle? @Sascha

Comment: As stated in my answer/comment to your original post: This method only works for a simple gradient with two colors. I'd like to know that too though.

Comment: Do you know how to change the color of the arrowheads? The end of the arrow is transparent, however, the arrowhead is still red. @Sascha

Comment: The first list entry (`Red` in my answer) determines the color of the arrow head

Comment: Graphics3D[{Directive[Red, Opacity@0], Thick, Arrow@Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, VertexColors -> {Red,Directive[Red, Opacity@0]}]}]  It will show nothing. I want the arrowhead is transparent too. @Sascha

Comment: If you want the arrowhead to be transparent you could leave it off as well :), but you are right setting the first list entry to `Opacity[0]` (instead of a visible color) makes the whole thing invisible.

Comment: OK, the problem is I want the arrowhead with opacity=0.1(for example). And I try to plot two arrows together to obtain three colors effect.